# Date manipulation and comparison in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a document that has the following properties

```
{
    _id: '1234',
    daysToExpire: 7,
    createdOn: 2018-10-16 08:06:19.856 (stored as a date in mongo)
}
```

I am trying to write an aggregation that says

*pseudo code:*

```
is the current date > $createdOn + $daysToExpire
```

I imagine the best approach would be to convert `$createdOn` to a number and then add `1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * $daysToExpire`

I've tried the following which doesn't work

```
$match: {
    createdOn: {
        $gt: [{ $add: ['$createdOn', '$daysToExpire']}, '$currentDate']
    }
}
```

or

```
$match: {
    createdOn: {
      $gt: { $subtract: ['$currentDate', '$daysToExpire' ] }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically you need [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/index.html) with [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/index.html) to perform some calculations on filtering. Inside of `$expr` you can just use [$add](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/add/) which considers second argument as the number of miliseconds if first one is **ISODate**. Below code works on 4.0:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $match:{
            $expr: {
                $gt: [ new Date(), // now as ISODate
                        { 
                            $add: [ 
                                "$createdOn", 
                                { $multiply: [ "$daysToExpire", 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24  ] } 
                            ] 
                        } 
                    ]
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I wasn't clear in my original post.. it's stored as a date in mongo.  I just presented it incorrectly.

Comment: So just get rid of `$toDate`

Comment: Thanks for the help @micki.  That worked.  I ran into problems with how mongo compass handles `new Date()`.   Your query worked great.